# Restrict View Elements to Certain Users in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm looking for a way to restrict certain elements to certain users, what I have - Teams and Users, Teams can have many users and the users can have many teams, each team has a "Team Leader" which is a user... so basically any user can be a team leader of team.

And here's my problem - because of this many-to-many relationship, I can't find a way to use Authorize(Role) on my problem.

For example - I log in on the website and go to the section of "My Teams" - Only the teams that I'm listed (as a user and as a manager) shows up - but without the restrictions, every option (edit, add members, etc...) shows up, whether or not I'm a team leader.

The solutions that I'm finding are Role based, so I'm just looking for something to point me in the right direction.

My TeamModel

```
public class EquipaModel
{
    [Key]
    public int EquipaID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display (Name="Nome")]
    public string EquipaNome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display (Name="Descrição")]
    public string EquipaDescricao { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Team Manager")]
    public string TeamManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser TeamManager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Membros { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You would need to perform those checks in the controller. If the users makes a request to (say) edit, but they are not the team leader (and only team leaders can edit), then redirect them to a another view with a friendly 'edit denied' message.

Comment: @StephenMuecke and what about [WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx) is it a good practice to implement it in MVC project or better not do it at all?

Comment: @teovankot, I don't use WIF, but I don't think it would solve this issue because the permissions are dependent on the information in the `Teams` and `Users` database which could be changing all the time

Comment: I had a similar requirement and decided to implement a CustomMembershipProvider as well as a CustomRoleProvider. I created some useful attributes that I now can use to limit controller methods to users with a given *UserLevel* or *Permission*.

Comment: @Robert, Does your `CustomMembershipProvider` call the database each time? If user A is the team leader, but is replaced by user B at some point, the only way you could ensure that only user B can edit at that point, is to make a database call each time the controller is called.

Comment: Yes, but I also use (EF + custom) caching in combination with DB triggers for minimum overhead.